# holomorphic sectional curvature and total scalar curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, curvature

In a paper of Heier and Wong, It is written  that from a pointwise argument due to Berger does follow  that the scalar curvature (and thus also the total scalar curvature) of a Kaehler metric of positive holomorphic sectional curvature is also positive.
I am looking for the paper of Berger ("Sur les varietέs d'Einstein compactes, C.R. IIIe Reunion Math. Expression latine, Namur (1965) 35-55") to which Heier is referring, but I don't have access to Berger's paper so I ask here to see if this can be proved very quickly or has been written in somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is exactly the same of the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42051/negative-holomorphic-sectional-curvature) older question of mine. Enjoy!